# Remove nested attribute in dynamodb

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Let's say I have this item in DynamoDB:

```
{
  "customerId": "customer_001",
  "customerName": "itsme",
  "address": {
    "city": "Frankfurt",
    "country": "Germany",
    "street1": "c/o Company xxx",
    "street2": "Europe",
    "street3": "PO Box 406",
    "zip": "12345"
  }
}
```

I need to remove the nested attribute `address.street3` from the item. How I can accomplish this?

Here is my code below; it works perfectly to remove non-nested attributes (for example, `customerName`), but if I try to use this in nested attributes (like `address.street3`), it silently fails.

```
const params = {
    TableName: customerTable,
    Key: {
        customerId: customerId,
    },
    AttributeUpdates: {
        'address.street3':
        {
            Action: 'DELETE'
        }
    }
};

dynamoDb.update(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to update customer. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    }
    else {
        console.log("UpdateCustomer succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data.Attributes));
        responseHelper.ResponseHelper.success(JSON.stringify(data.Attributes), 200, callback);
    }
});
```

What can I remove the nested attribute `address.street3`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is the code to remove "address.street3" attribute.

```
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

var params = {
        TableName : "customer",
        Key : {
            "customerId": "customer_001"            
        },
        UpdateExpression : "REMOVE address.street3",
        ReturnValues : "UPDATED_NEW"
    };

console.log("Updating the item...");
docClient.update(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to update item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("UpdateItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```

Comment: what if a key, instead of `street3` was `4b43641d-b5a5-4eda-8dca-5cfc677cb0ea`?

I tried `UpdateExpression : "REMOVE data.#id", ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#id': "4b43641d-b5a5-4eda-8dca-5cfc677cb0ea" }`


I tried `UpdateExpression : "REMOVE data.${id}"` where id = `4b43641d-b5a5-4eda-8dca-5cfc677cb0ea`

All failing. Ideas? Thanks

Comment: The second is failing probably because you need the backticks to do string interpolation, `REMOVE data.${id}` instead of "REMOVE data.${id}".

For the first one try doing # for data too, like so

UpdateExpression : "REMOVE #data.#id", ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#data': 'data', '#id': "4b43641d-b5a5-4eda-8dca-5cfc677cb0ea" }